# Mass password reset after Importing customers via CSV

Tags: import, customer-account, csv, password

I'm performing a large import of an existing customer base from a different platform.

I've exported their DB and written a script to make a CSV to import into Magento 1.9. Unfortunately, we do not have a password. Is there a way to have Magento generate one and send each customer, as we add them, an email to perform a reset? I couldn't find any links on a strategy here.

Answer (score 4):

You can write a script that gets all the newly imported customers and then it generates a new password and sends an email to your customers try this:

```
$customers = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        'created_at', 
        array('gteq', $dateYouImportedYourCustomers)
    );

foreach ($customers as $customer) {
    /** @var $customer Mage_Customer_Model_Customer */
    if ($customer->getId()) {
        try {
            $newResetPasswordLinkToken =  Mage::helper('customer')->generateResetPasswordLinkToken();
            $customer->changeResetPasswordLinkToken($newResetPasswordLinkToken);
            $customer->sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail();
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            Mage::log($exception);
        }
    }
}
```